# Whats wrong with this declaration, why doesn't it work on FF?

Tags: css, firefox

```
.img_woman{
    background:url(images/woman.png);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    display:block;
    width:235px;
    height:359px;
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:-120px;
}
```

The image does not appear on Firefox... it does work on Chrome, IE, Opera... no 404 error.

FireFox 24.0

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: Can you navigate to the file manually? Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Seems right. Try reproducing it in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is really weird. Seems like it has something to do with high contrast theme on Windows. I tried on other machine and it works perfectly fine. And on Laptop it simply doesn't load any images... any attached this way. It does download it, sends request, can view it in new tab, but doesn't display. Everything is white and text on button is green exactly as in Windows theme. The only image that shows up is <img />

Comment: Exactly the same happens on every other site. Even `stackoverflow`.

Comment: What does your screenshot of Stack Overflow have to do with the question?

Comment: Question was asked when I installed FireFox to test my application. Thought it could be css syntax or some FireFox bug, as google found alot of similar cases with image url as background. This seems to be normal that after few comments and investigation the subject of question changed. I did not delete the question because it wouldn't be fair, as people were trying to help.

Comment: Oh and I couldn't give a screenshot of my project.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the cache and cookies doesn't help it could be a profile issue. Try:
`Help > Troubleshooting Information -> Reset Firefox`

Failing that try:
`Help > Restart with Add-ons Disabled` to rule out any issues caused by add-ons.

Comment: The app was just installed, but tried all steps and still the same.